# How can I send HAC property changes to all nodes in a specific service in CCV2 Portal without triggering a rolling restart?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

How can I send HAC property changes to all nodes in a specific service (e.g. API or Backgroundprocessing service) in CCV2 Portal without triggering a rolling restart?

I'm aware that it's possible to add/change HAC properties using hcs_common under Environments > Services in CCV2 Portal. However, this makes the HAC properties permanent and causes the nodes to restart (using rolling restart). To revert the change, hcs_common needs to be updated again and another rolling restart needs to be triggered.

I'm also aware it's possible to expose an API that uses `ClusterAwareEvent`. Assuming I don't want to go this route (i.e. I don't want to make additional changes), is it possible to do what I need using a Groovy script that can be executed in HAC? Can I specify the service (e.g. API or Backgroundprocessing service) and send the HAC properties to all the nodes of that service?

Comment: I think the only possibility is through the services (there is a service per type: API, backoffice, ...). But that indeed performs a rolling restart of those nodes. With the clusterAwareEvent, new nodes that might be started won't have the correct properties set and might cause issues

Answer (score 0):

I think there is one way.

1. Create a groovy script and there use configurationService to populate new key and values.
2. then create scripting job.
3. create cronjob and there you can provide server node or if are having any cluster group that you can give it.
4. execute the cronjob

Comment: With this, you only change the property on a specific node, not all nodes of that specific type. As this runs in the cloud, you have no idea how many servers are actually running (well you can through the hac if you want). In theory, more nodes can be started and those won't have the property set